# D3 elements being removed although I'm only adding new ones

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's been a while since I picked up [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) and it seems I'm a bit rusty. I'm trying to do a form where I can add more input fields by clicking `+` and removing the existing ones by clicking `-`.

To try and discover what I had wrong, I started colouring the `enter()`, update and `exit()` with green, yellow and red respectively.

The original data array has two elements, so they show up as green:

[image]

Then I click on the plus sign which pushes a new element to the array, and I expected to see two yellows and one green, but instead I see all the elements deleted besides the last one, and this repeats if I click + again:

[image]

And plus again:

[image]

I've compared my code with the classic [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) and I can't see anything significant apart from the way I set the keys, in which I use the e-mail. This is code I've added to fix another underlying issue where not all the boxes were being added, just one out of each 3.

My commented code is as follows:

```
var renderFriends = function () {

  console.log("Rendering friends:" + friendsList)

  var friends = d3.select('.friends-container')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(friendsList, function(d,i) {
      // this was something I added when I thought the problem were the keys
      return d
    })

  // updates will be yellow
  friends.classed("update", true)

  var enter = friends.enter()

  // Friend box
  // all the divs are because I'm using foundation css
  // the new class is what marks the font green
  var friendBox = enter.append('div').classed('large-12 columns new', true)

  friendBox.append('div').classed('large-8 columns', true)
    .append("input")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("value", String)

  // Icon box
  var iconBox = friendBox.append('div').classed('large-2 left columns', true)
    .append("i")
    .classed('fi-minus', true)
    .on("click", function(d) {
      // out of scope for this question
      console.log("Removing:" + d)
      friendsList.remove(friendsList.indexOf(d))
      renderFriends()
     })

  // exit state should colour the fonts red
  friends.exit().classed('remove', true)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small test with custom styles and this is what got (when I clicked minus button):

[image]

All elements have green background since they all have "new" class, the "update" elements have yellow border, and the "remove" red background.
So what I've noticed is that you have a various Divs nested, and the problem is that when you do a selectAll('div') is going to select all divs and d3 is expecting for each div element being selected to be a data element corresponding to it.

So if you want to add another element and your friendsList is:

```
friendsList = ['a@test.com','b@test.com','c@test.com'];
```

d3.selectAll('div') is going to take 6 divs (when you had 2 friends and added one), and its going to bind only 3 elements because your dataset contains only 3 friends, and its going to target the rest of elements as "exiting".

To solve this, simply change your select using a class like '.friend' and also add it to each element being inserted (only the main container div);
Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2codv59e/

Comment: I sometimes forget how advanced d3 selectors are, if this was jQuery I would remember that I was selecting all the inner divs, but I was thinking just of my problem, I got it now. thanks.